# Judging the People in Mea Shearim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The last line of Tehillim 98 says "ישפט תבל בצדק ועמים במאה שערים" - "He will judge the world with righteousness and people in Mea Shearim."

Why will Hashem only judge the people in Mea Shearim?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's Gateshead's sister city

Answer (score 5):

You've mis-distributed the verb. The verse should be read to mean "He will judge the world with righteousness and with the people in Mea Shearim" (with the ב before צדק being distributed to both צדק and עמים במאה שערים).

An important part of the judgement is the burning fires of Gehinnom. Since the residents of Mea Shearim have much experience with managing large fires<sup>1</sup>, they will be on hand to light any necessary judgement-related fires.

---

<sup>1</sup> Random sample [here](http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/news-photo/orthodox-jews-walk-past-burning-garbage-bins-june-25-2009-news-photo/88685980#orthodox-jews-walk-past-burning-garbage-bins-june-25-2009-in-the-picture-id88685980)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps they are on a unique spiritual level and aare therefore treated differently. We see this idea in Job ([15:15](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2715.htm)):

> הֵן בִּקְדֹשָׁו, לֹא יַאֲמִין
>
> Behold, He putteth no trust in His holy ones.

Similarly, Yevamot ([121b](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.121b?lang=bi)) states:

> מלמד, שהקדוש ברוך הוא מדקדק עם סביביו כחוט השערה
>
> This teaches that God is exacting with those around him to a hairsbreadth.

Since he doesn't trust these holy ones who are closest to him, apparently he subjects them to special judgement.

Answer (score 3):

> ישפט תבל בצדק ועמים במאה שערים

This verse is talking about agriculture.

תבל is of course untithed produce. צדק (as in Proverbs 11:18, "וזרע צדקה שכר אמת / and planting צדקה is truly beer") is barley. Thus, "He will judge untithed produce with barley": He'll judge those who don't tithe by making their ground suitable only for growing barley, a crop inferior to the more common staple, wheat.

עמים, then, is tithed produce, so called because it is shared among *kohanim*, *l'viim*, and *yisr'elim*. "And [He will judge] tithed produce with a one-hundredfold": God rewards tithing with מאה שערים, one hundred times as much produce as was expected (as in Genesis 26:12).

Answer (score 3):

Because Meah Shearim has probably one of the largest amount of religious Jews and Kollels (sorry Lakewood), it probably has one of the largest amount of Dayanim.

Now, there's a principle of [קשט עצמך ואחר כך קשט אחרים](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.18a?lang=bi)  (correct yourself and only then correct others) which says  that only one that is judged can judge others (and if one cannot be judged, for whatever reason, he cannot sit on a court).

So since all the Dayanim want to sit on courts, they want to be judged, and Dovid Hamelech is praying to Hashem to fulfill their hearts desire.

Answer (score 1):

I am SO glad that you asked this question, as this is one of the fundamental lessons for how all of humanity should behave.

Before I begin, I must mention that you have mistranslated the verse. There are two distinct parts, here - 1) The world will be judged with righteousness. 2) The rest of the nations, will be judged by the standards of Me'ah She'arim.

Now, where in the Torah is Me'ah She'arim mentioned? Look in Breishit 26:12. It was actually Isaac that started the community of Me'ah SHe'arim.

A synopsis of the story - Because of a famine, Isaac escapes to live with the king of the Phillistines in Gerar. After living there a while, he becomes very successful, and establishes the town of Me'ah SHe'arim, pretty much funding the village with his own funds.

Now, what happens afterwards? The Phillistines become jealous of him and start stuffing up his wells (actually those from Abraham, that belong to Isaac, now.) The king doesn't do anything about it, and says to Isaac, "Get out of here because you're overwhelming us."

What a shame, no? They're jealous of Isaac's success. But, instead of learning from Isaac's example, they kick him out. And notice that the Torah doesn't say that they were jealous of Isaac's success. They were jealous of Isaac, himself, as a person.

See something familiar, today from this story? Jews are a very successful people. The other nations are jealous of the Jews, which is one of the main reasons of Anti-Semitism. (You may want to read "Why the Jews?" by Telushkin, as he expounds on this point far better than I can.)

All this began from the example of Me'ah She'arim - that village that Isaac started. So the verse that you cited says that G-d will judge the other nations according to the standards of behavior exhibited by the nations as a result of Me'ah She'arim.