# PTIJ - Please resolve apparent conflict on what was supposed to be thrown for the plaugue of boils

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There appears to be a conflict between what G-d says should be thrown skyward for the plague of boils (שחין) and what was actually done.

In Shemot 9:8, when G-d is saying what should occur, it says:

> וזרקו משה השמימה לעיני פרעה
>
> They shall throw Moses towards the sky before Pharaoh's eyes

But, when Moses appears before Pharaoh, Shemot 9:10 it says:

> ויקחו את פיח הכבשו ויעמדו לפני פרעה ויזרק אתו משה השמימה...
>
> They took the oven soot, stood before Pharaoh. They threw him
> skywards...

I assume that the word "him" in the above verse refers to Pharaoh, and they (Moses and Aharon) threw him skyward.

I'm puzzled here. Why does G-d command that Moses should be thrown skyward, but when they actually do it, Moses disobeys G-d's command and throws Pharaoh, instead?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Its those darn unreliable really holy people הן בקדשיו לא יאמין. [Again](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80626/judging-the-people-in-mea-shearim/80627#80627).

Answer (score 0):

There is another interpretation of וזרקו משה השמימה לעיני פרעה that make more sense in this case.  Some translate this Passuk as:

> And Moshe shall throw Pharaoh's eyes into the sky

If this is the case, then when Moshe threw Pharaoh as a whole into the sky, then he was simply being machmir.

A real (!) source for this Rav Avraham ben Harambam to Shemos 9:8 ([here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/?mode=basic&t=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%94#!SP/R.%20Avraham%20b.%20HaRambam/Shemot/9.8)), suggests that Einei Pharaoh means throwing the eyes that are part of a standing Pharaoh, in which case Moshe fulfilled the commandment in full.

> לעיני פרעה – במעמד פרעה.

Comment: @uber_chacham see the original edit of the question, which had the same error - that must have gotten it into my head:  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/80653/revisions

Comment: I guess I also missed it over there. By the way, why can't I make an edit of just 1 or 2 characters, as is normally the case? I can't access the meta, as my filter wont let me, so I don't know if there is an answer over there.